# SOM multiple BMU, need to work on one random one or all of it

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, unsupervised-learning, self-organizing-maps

I am currently learning my own self organized map (SOM). I am new to this. The nodes are all initialized with random values. I was wondering, what do I need to do if there is a case that return multiple BMU during the training session. For the update phase, do I need to take only one of them, or all of them?

Comment: In general, you take one randomly. It is good to ensure diversity among the clusters.

Answer (score 3):

In original SOM algorithm only one neuron is selected as BMU (The neuron which has the closest wieght vector to the input vector). Then weights of BMU and its neighbors are updated.